# Google Chrome Extension: How to create a right click extension with hierarchy branches?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, right-click

I want to be able to add multiple options to my right click extension. I currently have one and it works as should, but I copied a simple tutorial and need a bit more guidance. Thank you for any assistance.

```
// Set up context menu at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "selection";
  var title = "Search on blah blah";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                         "id": "context" + context});  
});

// add click event
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

// The onClicked callback function.
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  var sText = info.selectionText;
  var url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(sText);  
  window.open(url, '_blank');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [chrome.contextMenus.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create), you can create a child context menu item (hierachy branches) by setting `parentId`

```
// Set up context menu at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "selection";
  var title = "Search on blah blah";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                     "id": "context" + context});  
  var child1_id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "child1", "parentId": id, "contexts":[context],
                                     "id": "child1_id"}); 
  var child2_id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "child2", "parentId": id, "contexts":[context],
                                     "id": "child2_id"}); 

});

// add click event
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

// The onClicked callback function.
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  var sText = info.selectionText;
  var url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(sText);  
  window.open(url, '_blank');
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I'll do better reading next time.